# How to resolve dependency based on type as string using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a generic interface, say `IGeneric` which I want to resolve dynamically based on the types that I have as `string`. To make it clearer, I can resolve the dependency like this:

```
container.Resolve<IGeneric<AType>>();
```

But my question is how to resolve it when I have this:

```
var type = "AType";
```

Is there any way apart from (better than) registering every possible class that can be used in place of `AType` as a named instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the prototype of [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650946.aspx) that accepts a `Type`.

```
Type type = System.Type.GetType("AType");
var instance = container.Resolve(type);
```

Or (not sure which one you want) to resolve for `IGeneric<Atype>` use:

```
Type genericType = typeof(IGeneric<>);
Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(new [] {Type.GetType("AType")});
var instance = container.Resolve(specificType );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (especially after Or...). I'll give it a try now, but I'm not sure if it is better (performance wise) than defining typed instances (though there will be plenty of binds).

Comment: BTW, instance is an object not an IGeneric, so with this approach I lose some control. Consider, how can I call a method of instance?

Comment: The return type of `Resolve(Type)` is an object, but it should reference an instance of the right class.  So just cast, e.g. `IGeneric<AType> x = instance as IGeneric<AType>;` With late binding you will always have to cast.

Comment: If I had AType I would resolve it at first place like `container.Resolve<IGeneric<TypeA>>`. I think this was a design issue that I had, so after some discussion I moved the resolution one level closer to the implementation where I can explicitly resolve the generic based on the type that I want.